# mi.yodeya.com path-URLs strip the path on redirecting

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, site-name

`http://mi.yodeya.com/[anything]` now redirects straight to `http://judaism.stackexchange.com` rather than to `http://judaism.stackexchange.com/[anything]` as it used to. This seems like a bug; if it is (and I hope not!) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), then we'll need to fix all the links (strewn about the site) linking to URLs of the first sort I mention to link to URLs of the last sort instead.

(Same for `miyodeya.com` and `yodeya.com`.)

Comment: I suspect this is temporary, until the domain transfer business is completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an issue with our load balancer configuration.  I corrected the issue a moment ago.  Sorry for the inconvenience!

```
--2012-07-18 09:53:42--  http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/8496/time-travel-and-judaism  
Resolving mi.yodeya.com (mi.yodeya.com)... 64.34.119.12  
Connecting to mi.yodeya.com (mi.yodeya.com)|64.34.119.12|:80... connected.  
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently  
Location: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8496/time-travel-and-judaism [following]
```

Comment: I'm still seeing it. Perhaps I need to wait 24 hours or clear some cache?