# mi.yodeya rss feed no longer updating

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mi.yodeya.com path-URLs strip the path on redirecting](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/mi-yodeya-com-path-urls-strip-the-path-on-redirecting)

Just a heads up. I was subscribed to    https://judaism.stackexchange.com/feeds , and the last feed update was 7/10.

Google reader says "A parsing error was encountered."

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/feeds is working fine.

I'm sure this is just part of the yodeya.com issues, but thought I'd give people a heads up.

Comment: Yep, that'll be the same issue. Once http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/mi-yodeya-com-path-urls-strip-the-path-on-redirecting is fixed, http://mi.yodeya.com/feeds should redirect fine to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/feeds.